# activeItemChange: How to speed up its performance?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

In an attempt to optimize my app's performance, I've tried to cut down the number of elements in its main carousel as much as possible. I'm down to 3 first-order items (the one being viewed, along with N-1 and N+1).

I'd also like to cut out most of the contents of the N-1 and N+1 carousel items and programmatically add the contents for the item that is currently being viewed (so that the carousel items would look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1dUj.png).

`activeItemChange` is the obvious choice here for the event listener. Problem is, it apparently is relatively slow, especially on low-end Android phones. It can take as long as 4 seconds to fire.

I've tried the carousel's `onDrag` property as a different way to fire the content creation, but asking the phone to do two operations (animate the carousel moving & create the new content items) makes the carousel movement animation choppy.

Is there any way to modify activeItemChange or the carousel to improve the listener's firing speed? Or any other listener I could be looking at that would perform better? I've done quite a lot of work optimizing overall performance on the app (shrinking the DOM, event delegation, etc) and the rest of the app runs quite well, so I'm not sure that doing general performance work will free up sufficient CPU to get activeItemChange to the level that I'd like.

**Edit:** I've done even more performance improvements in an attempt to free up enough CPU, to no avail. Any additional tips would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit 2:** It's been suggested to use `order: 'before'` for the event, as in:

```
listeners : {
    order : 'before',
    activeitemchange : someFunction
}
```

That does fire much more quickly. However, since activeItemChange has necessarily not been fired yet, I can't determine which item should get the carousel contents added. If I could determine which direction the carousel is going, that would be sufficient, but I can't seem to get that either.

Additionally, since Sencha seems to automatically paint N+1 and N-1 and erases N+2 and N-2, I was thinking I could use that as a more rapid determinant of where the item is in the carousel; unfortunately, based on the performance issues brought up in the Sencha documentation, it seems like it would end up with worse performance rather than better in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Just a suggestion may or may not work. Instead of concentrating on the activeItemChange of the carousel maybe you could try the painted event of the container into which you want to put your items, or initialize event if the data is not going to change, initialize is faster than painted but only fires once so if your content is going to change use painted, otherwise try it out with initialize it may be the better way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately Sencha Touch automatically paints items N+1 and N-1 in the carousel, so I wouldn't be able to make sure that just item N has the contents. Tricky problem indeed.